# Can I change the URL of a Google Apps service installed from the Google Apps marketplace?

Tags: google-workspace, url

If I install a service such as Docs, Calendar, or Wave in my Google Apps account I get the ability to change the URL of the service from the stock-standard `https://www.google.com/[service]/hosted/[my domain]` to something more meaningful.

As a result, my calendar service is at `http://calendar.[mydomain]`, documents is at `http://docs.[mydomain]`, etc.

However if I install a service from the Google Apps marketplace, I don't get the option to change the URL.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third-party apps are usually hosted off-site, so its really up to the app provider to allow that or not.

If you have a web server at your site or a shared hosting provider or similar, you could set up a simple redirection yourself.

Comment: My domain is hosted elsewhere, so that's definitely an option.  Will a CNAME entry suffice or am I looking for something else?

Comment: You'll need to talk to your hosting provider. It typically involves point the DNS record at their web server (A or CNAME) and then some web server config to make the redirection happen.

The shared hosting provider I use has enough options in their control panel that I could set this up myself there. I don't know what other providers offer so I can't comment.